Understanding Adding slack variable to build standard form
I first encountered adding slack variables when learning solving LP problems. It is a little strange to me.
Given a general LP,
max $ c^{T} x$ subject to
$Ax \leq b$
$Bx \geq d$
$Cx = e$
I need to transform it into a standard form (For example, all constraints are equalities, all variables are non-negative). I need to do things like $x_1= y_1-y_2$ where $ y_1, y_2 \geq 0$, add or minus slack variables to the inequalities.
By doing so, why we can guarantee the optimize question is the same? It seems to me we build a bijection $f$ between two constraints sets. If one is empty, then the other. $x$ is a feasible solution to original problem iff $f(x)$ is feasible to the modified one. $x$ is optimal solution to original problem iff $f(x)$ is optimal to the modified one. Is it true? Or should I understand in another way?

Let me drop the $Bx \le d$ constraint since that form can be incorporated into $Ax \le b$.
$$\max c^Tx \tag{A}$$
subject to
$$Ax \le b$$
$$Cx=e$$
Let's convert it to the standard form.
$$\max c^Ty_1 - c^Ty_2 \tag{B}$$
subject to
$$Ay_1-Ay_2 +s_1 =b$$
$$Cy_1-Cy_2 = e$$
$$y_1, y_2, s_1 \ge 0$$
For every feasible solution in (A), we show that we can find a feasible solution in (B) that share the same objective value and for every feasible solution in (B), we can find a feasible solution in (A) that share the same objective value.
Given $x$ that is feasible in (A), if $x_i \ge 0$, then $y_{1i} = x_i$ and $y_{2i} = 0$, otherwise $y_{1i} = 0$ and $y_{2i}=-x_i$. We can verify that $x=y_1-y_2$ holds and let $s_1=b-Ax$. We can also verify that the objective value remain the same.
Given $(y_1, y_2, s)$ in $(B)$, we just have to let $x=y_1-y_2$ and verify that it is feasible and the objective value remain the same.

SO you do agree that we build a bijection between the feasible solutions of (A) and (B)? And one nice property is this bijection preserves the objective value?

It is not a bijection. Notice that if $(y_1, y_2, s)$ and $(y_1 + 1, y_2 + 1, s)$ are both mapped to the same $x$.

So the equivalence of these two LP problems means 1. A has feasible solution iff B does.  2. A and B shares the same optimal (Infinite or finite). We do not need to guarantee there is no loss of solutions (as you pointed out, two solutions may condense to one) after the transformation.

We can sort of maps the solutions to of $B$ into equivalence classes where two points $(y_1, y_2, s)$ and $(\hat{y}_1, \hat{y}_2, \hat{s})$ are equivalent if $y_1-y_2 = \hat{y}_1 - \hat{y}_2$ and $s=\hat{s}$.

One of the core reasons we bother with standardization is for the Simplex method, which is the primary method for solving linear programs (Slide 4). When one standardizes the problem, they are reducing it to the boundaries of the feasible region. One cares about these boundary points as anything in the interior is not optimal (see this). In fact, the optimal solution(s) only happen on the extreme points of the program (see this). Therefore, the point of standardization is to reduce the problem to the boundaries for the Simplex method to solve by letting it traverse the boundary from extreme point to extreme point. The standard form is equivalent to the original problem in that the slack picks up any excess/surpluss the $x$ values do not satisfy for the constraints in order for the boundary to be satisfied.

A minor nitpick on the sentence "In fact, the optimal solution(s) only happen on the extreme points of the program (see this)." (emphasis is mine). "There always is an optimal solution at an extreme point, whenever a solution exists in the first place" would be correct.
